# Object values not being passed

Tags: mysql, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.6 and having an issue passing data to my blade file.

BlogController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\Practice;
use App\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Post;
use Session;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
  public function getSingle($slug){
    // Fetch from the DB based on Slug --first stops after one, get pulls everything
  $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
  print_r($slug);

  // return the view and pass in the post object
  return view('blog.single')->withPost($post);

 }
}
```

single.blade.php:

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', "| $post->title")

@section('content')


  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <h1>{{ $post->title}}</h1>
    <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
</div>
```

@stop

I verified the name and spelling in the DB (MySQL.) If I `dd($slug)` or `print_r($slug)` the results are correct.

However, if I do the same but use `$title` or `$body` it returns the error

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/jesseburger/myproject/resources/views/blog/single.blade.php)

I have been able to verify its pulling an empty array by using `print_r($post)` but can't figure out why.

`print_r($post)` yields:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )

Current route:

```
Route::get('blog/{slug}', [
    'as' => 'blog.single', 
    'uses' => 'BlogController@getSingle'
])->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
```

Comment: Is `withPost` actually a function in Laravel? Maybe try `return view('blog.single')->with('post', $post);`, or `return view('blog.single', ['post' => $post]);`.

Comment: You really should implement something that handles when there isn't a post found.  Then you wouldn't even need to print_r, you'd know there's a Post.

Comment: Ive tried both suggestions but its still pulling an empty array

Answer (score 3):

Your return statement is incorrect, you need to change this line:

```
return view('blog.single')->withPost($post);
```

To this, it should resolve your issue.

```
return view('blog.single')->with('post', $post);
```

Comment: its kicking back "Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance." after implementing the withPost to with('post', $post)

Comment: Can you check the contents of `$post` in your view with `print_r($post);`

Comment: its just loading an empty page

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )        This is what its kicking back

Comment: Try: `Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();` instead of `Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();`

Comment: Thats loading a completely blank page

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: I can print_r($slug) but if i try to pull $title or $body it gives the undefined error

Comment: And you are sure that theres a record that matches the query?

Comment: in blade Im calling it in two locations. first in the @section('title', "| $post->title") Second in the body using {{ $post->title }}

Comment: Yes, I have two records with slugs in my DB and I can call them elsewhere just not from this controller

Comment: Are you getting the slug from the url?

Comment: Add your routes to the post

Comment: Here is my route: Route::get('blog/{slug}', ['as' => 'blog.single', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getSingle'])->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');

Comment: I'm following the tutorial by DevMarketer on building a blog with Laravel and this is video 24 in the series. Just so you know where I am coming from

Comment: Not sure how but it decided to start working! I hate it when it this happens because I am unable to see the mistake and therefore unable to learn how to prevent it...

Comment: Weird haha, welcome in the world of programming :). Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

First you are debugging your slug not your post. Try to debug your post to see if it was found. You are getting that error because the post doesn't exist at all. Abort if it doesn't exist.

```
if(!$post){
    abort(404);
}
```